# One update SQL query from three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables and I have to write one query to update table 1 row from table 3 and the only matching columns I have is in table 2.

Table 1 which has incorrect data:

[image]

Table 3 has the correct data:

[image]

I did try to write a query and execute it but it gives me an error saying there are too many rows too select which is true I do have many rows to correct but it still wouldn't correct. What do you think I should do. This is my query so far.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Number = (SELECT Table3.Number 
                     FROM Table2 
                     FULL OUTER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
                     FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Signin = Table2.Signin
                     WHERE (Table2.ID = Table1.ID) 
                       AND (Table1.Number = 'xxx'))
WHERE (Tale1.Number = 'xxx')
```

Comment: which rdbms (mysql, sql-server, oralce, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually worked after I removed this line from my query.

> FULL OUTER JOIN Table1 ON table1.ID = Table2.ID

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like the `AND (Table1.Number = 'xxx')` in the inner query is redundant. Is there a reason you're using full outer join?

Answer (score 2):

In Where clause of JOIN query need to modify as multiple records are generating by inappropriate condition.Try to use Table3 components instead of using Table1 in joining query where clause.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.NUMBER = (SELECT table3.NUMBER FROM Table1 FULL OUTER JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
  FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 
  ON Table2.SIGNIN = Table3.SIGNIN
  WHERE Table3.SIGNIN = 100) // This is the point where you need to modify your code
WHERE Table1.ID = 1;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO HERE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/505803)</kbd>

Comment: @Nick I have made some changes according to you latest edit. Check this out.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You are fairly close.  When doing the update though unless you are wanting to clear value for t1.number when a record is not matched in t3, you will  want to use `INNER JOIN`.  `FULL OUTER JOIN` would mean you are trying to update rows in t1 that don't exist but a `LEFT JOIN` you would update t1.number to NULL if a record in t3 doesn't exist.

```
 UPDATE t1
    SET t1.Number = t3.Number 
FROM
    Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t2.Signin = t.3.Signin
WHERE
    t1.number <> t3.number
    --Or if you have nulls something like
    --ISNULL(t1.number,'xxx') <> ISNULL(t3.number,'xxx')
    -- if you only want to update when t1.number = 'xxx' then
    --t1.number = 'xxx'
```

t1,t2,t3 are table aliases that I created by adding the alias after table name.  By using join syntax rather than a sub select you simplify your were conditions.  In sql-sever if more than 1 record in t2 & t3 match it will select one row randomly in the case of a one to many relationship.  If you want a specific record when not one to one relation you can use window functions and common table expressions (cte) to limit t3 to the exact record you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the help